# How to avoid HTML script when web service returns

Tags: xml, web-services, c#-2.0

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod]

public string sampleTest()
{
    string name = "";
    name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"];

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<message>");
    sb.Append("<categoryname =" + name + "/>");
    sb.Append("</message>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Invoking method :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];


    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/mylytica/apibridge.asmx/sampleTest?name=Shankar");

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.GetResponse();

    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (count != 0)
        {
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
            sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    }

    while (count > 0);

    Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Literal value contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">&lt;message loginstatus="OK" userid="1" /&gt;</string>
```

Actual Format:

```
<message loginstatus="OK" userid="1" />
```

What i have to do.

Comment: Actual Format i need is:<message loginstatus="OK" userid="1" />

Comment: but i getting value like this:&gtmessage loginstatus="OK" userid="1" /&gt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod]


public XmlDocument login(string username, string password)
{
       XmlDocument oXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
       XmlNode oXmlmessage = oXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "message", "");
       XmlAttribute oxmllogin = oXmlDoc.CreateAttribute("loginstatus");
       oxmllogin.InnerText = "OK";

       XmlAttribute oXmluserid = oXmlDoc.CreateAttribute("userid");
       oXmluserid.InnerText = iRegID.ToString();

       oXmlmessage.Attributes.Append(oxmllogin);
       oXmlmessage.Attributes.Append(oXmluserid);

       oXmlDoc.AppendChild(oXmlmessage);

       return oXmlDoc;
}
```

Comment: Finally i have fond the soln..frustrating ... i didnt get any response from editors .... really frustrating :(